# whats the difference between 101 and 102 key keyboards, and which do i need for UK laptop

Tags: laptop, keyboard-layout

I want to replace the US keyboard on my laptop with a UK one. I thought that UK keyboards were 102 and US were 101 as my Uk one has a (#) key and the US one doesn't.

But the UK replacement part keyboard specifies 101 keys, so I am now confused. Can someone set me straight on this...!

Answer (score 3):

Some languages that use considerably more than 26 letters has 102 key keyboard leyouts. Spanish and Hungarian are two examples. For English, 101 keys should be enough. There might be slight differences in the layout, but the important thing is that you set the layout in your OS the same as it is on your keyboard.

Comment: Ha, my laptop has 87 keys and my desktop has 103 keys!

Comment: @Tom: Yes, standard 101 or 102 key keyboards doesn't have the Win and the context menu keys. Laptop keyboards also lack the numpad and other keys. Nevertheless, they all can have 101 and 102 key layouts. For example, the 102 key Hungarian layout has a "0" in tplace of the "~", and a "Í" on the 102th key. The 101 key variant has the "Í" in place of the "~", and the "0" is only on the numpad.

Answer (score 1):

You don't mention who your laptop manufacturer is, but assuming your laptop is still within its warranty period you should be able to go back to their UK subsidiary and directly order a UK keyboard *(with the quote, £, #, @ and € signs in the right places)* for your model from them.

Comment: its not, its 4 years old

Answer (score 0):

I strongly believe you'll have absolutely no problems with either of them ... a laptop or a desktop, keyboard is still a keyboard.

As long as everything else is the same (by that I mean that it fits into your laptop and everything) it should give you no trouble.